# How can Sonar be configured to import new rulesets?

Tags: sonarqube

With maven-pmd-plugin, I am able to configure it to scan my unit tests for PMD violations:

`<configuration>`
  `<rulesets>`
    `<ruleset>/rulesets/junit.xml</ruleset>`
  `</rulesets>`

Sonar 2.0.1 doesn't seem to provide any way to add in new rulesets that I can see.  Has anyone figured out how to do this?

Answer (score 4):

The rules are defined in the sonar server as a set of configurations for pmd, findbugs, checkstyle etc.

You have to reference a configuration in your pom file (see the sonar [documentation/wiki](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Documentation)).

the property is [sonar.profile](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Quality+profiles)

But basically you will assign the profile for the project in the sonar server configuration.
(see Profiles Section in the [Wiki](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analysis+Parameters)). Profiles will also allow you to move rule configurations between environments, e.g. between development and production.