# importing existing checkstyle in sonar

Tags: sonarqube

I am trying to configure Sonarqubue for our project, however experiencing few issues.
We are using checkstyle5.5 and with our own defined set of rules, and few extra jars.
When I try to import our own checkstyle.xml, instead of using that it over rides and run checkstyle 5.6
Can any1 guide me, how to import our own checkstyle?
I have gone through this like, but of not help.
[How can Sonar be configured to import new rulesets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5619106/how-can-sonar-be-configured-to-import-new-rulesets)

Currently I am suing sonar runner analyser, not maven or ant analyzer.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

See the following plugin sample to add your custom rules: https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-examples/tree/master/plugins/sonar-checkstyle-extension-plugin

Comment: Thanks for answering, issue is I wanna use my existing Checkstyle rule, and it is not allowing to do the same